# Trying to use PHP DOM to replace node text without changing child nodes

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to use the dom object to simplify the implementation of a glossary tooltip. What I need to do is to replace a text element in a paragraph, but NOT in an anchor tag that may be embedded in the paragraph.

```
$html = '<p>Replace this tag not this <a href="#">tag</a></p>';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->validateOnParse = true;

$nodes = $document->getElementByTagName("p");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->nodeValue = str_replace("tag","element",$node->nodeValue);
}
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

I get:

```
'...<p>Replace this element not this element</p>...'
```

I want:

```
'...<p>Replace this element not this <a href="#">tag</a></p>...'
```

How do I implement this such that only the parent node text is changed and the child node (a tag) is not changed?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$html = '<p>Replace this tag not this <a href="#">tag</a></p>';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->validateOnParse = true;

$nodes = $document->getElementsByTagName("p");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    while( $node->hasChildNodes() ) {
        $node = $node->childNodes->item(0);
    }
    $node->nodeValue = str_replace("tag","element",$node->nodeValue);
}
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
To answer @paul's question in the comments below, you can create

```
$html = '<p>Replace this tag not this <a href="#">tag</a></p>';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->validateOnParse = true;

$nodes = $document->getElementsByTagName("p");

//create the element which should replace the text in the original string
$elem = $document->createElement( 'dfn', 'tag' );
$attr = $document->createAttribute('title');
$attr->value = 'element';
$elem->appendChild( $attr );

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    while( $node->hasChildNodes() ) {
        $node = $node->childNodes->item(0);
    }
    //dump the new string here, which replaces the source string
    $node->nodeValue = str_replace("tag",$document->saveHTML($elem),$node->nodeValue);
}
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pushpesh. This does work great. Could you help me better understand the DOM object by explaining what the while loop does. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking for that as well and have an extending question: if I also want to build a glossary, I don't want to just replace `tag` by `element` but by `<dfn title="element">tag</dfn>`. Thus, I would be adding a new child and need to split the `#text` node, correct? How would I achieve that?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I kind of tried in the same way, but it wouldn't work to put HTML into a #text node. I ended up using DOMDocumentFragment and replace the #text node with that fragment.

Comment: Doesn't work for <p>Replace this tag not this <a href="#">tag</a> and this tag as well</p> due to the while loop.